# Someone said that there's a Jewish source which claims that Satan cries when we do something bad? Does anyone know where this is from?

Tags: sources-mekorot, evil-resha, evil-inclination, satan

I've recently heard someone claim that there is a Jewish source which states that Satan cries when we do something evil.

As the question title says, does anyone know where this is coming from?

Comment: Perhaps the parable of the Harlot from the Zohar, bright at the end of Tanya chapter 9 - https://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/7888/jewish/Chapter-9.htm